# How to insert a tag before the root in XML with VBA

Tags: xml, vba

I developed the following code

```
    Set UBLdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set root = UBLdoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocument")
    
' Set the xmlns attribute for the root element
    root.setAttribute "xmlns", "http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"

' Create the StandardBusinessDocumentHeader element
    Set elem = UBLdoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocumentHeader")
' Append the StandardBusinessDocumentHeader element to the root element
    root.appendChild elem
...
' Append the root element to the document
    UBLdoc.appendChild root
```

that correctly generates the following XML.

```
<StandardBusinessDocument xmlns="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">
    <StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
        <HeaderVersion>1.0</HeaderVersion>
        <Sender>
            <Identifier Authority="iso6523-actorid-upis">0211:IT09229211009</Identifier>
        </Sender>
        <Receiver>
            <Identifier Authority="iso6523-actorid-upis">9934:27788012253</Identifier>
        </Receiver>
...
    </StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
...
</StandardBusinessDocument>
```

I need to insert the tag.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` 
before the `<StandardBusinessDocument>` tag. I am afraid I don't understand the exact meaning, but it is necessary for the XML to be accepted.

Is there anyone who can help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create XML declaration with `createProcessingInstruction`
- *Note:* `UTF-8` is default encoding, so the declaration may be as `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>`

```vb
Sub CreateXML()
    ' Create XML document
    Set ubldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    
    ' Create XML declaration and append it to the document
    Set xmlDeclaration = ubldoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'")
    ubldoc.appendChild xmlDeclaration
    
    ' Create root element
    Set Root = ubldoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocument")
    
    ' Set the xmlns attribute for the root element
    Root.setAttribute "xmlns", "http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"

    ' Create the StandardBusinessDocumentHeader element
    Set elem = ubldoc.createElement("StandardBusinessDocumentHeader")
    
    ' Append the StandardBusinessDocumentHeader element to the root element
    Root.appendChild elem

    ' Append the root element to the document
    ubldoc.appendChild Root
    
    ' Display the XML document
    Debug.Print ubldoc.XML
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [XmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction(String, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createprocessinginstruction?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=net-8.0)

Comment: Thank a lot! It works perfectly. FYI encoding="UTF-8" has been included in the declaration.